# Lebesgue Mean Value Theorem

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory

*Disclaimer: This proof is taken out from Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.*

---

Let $\Omega$ be a finite measure space $\lambda(\Omega)<\infty$.

Denote the mean value by:
$$M_E(f):=\frac{1}{\lambda(E)}\int_Efd\lambda\quad(\lambda(E)>0)$$

Consider a closed convex set $S$. Then:
$$M_E(f)\in S\quad(E\in\Sigma)\implies f(\omega)\in S\quad(\omega\in\Omega)$$
where the RHS evidently holds only almost everywhere.

For the proof it suffices to consider closed disks in the complement $\overline{D_r(a)}\subseteq S^c$
since countably many of these cover it $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\overline{D_n}}\subseteq S^c$.

But why is this so?

My first guess was that this is about totally boundedness but they're not allowed to lap into the closed convex set. Compactness seems also not to fit in here as there seems to be no compact set involved.

Moreover, do the disks need to be closed?

Comment: You can also work with open disks, but if the disks are closed it is easier to see that the mean value of $f$ over $E$ lies in the disk when $f(x)\in D$ for $x\in E$ and $\lambda(E) > 0$. As to "why is this so?", why is what so? That countably many closed disks cover $S^c$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yepp, why do countably many closed disks cover $S^c$?

Comment: You can write $S^c$ as a countable union of open disks - why? - and each of these open disks you can write as a countable union of closed disks.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hmm, I'm sorry, I see neither why your first statement holds nor your second. Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}$ is second countable. In particular, the open disks with (positive of course) rational radius and rational (both real and imaginary part rational) centre are a basis of the topology. So every open set can be written as a countable union of open disks (with rational radii and centres, if one wants that). And every open disk $B_r(z)$ can be written as a countable union of closed disks

$$B_r(z) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B_{(1-2^{-n})r}(z)},$$

hence every open set also can be written as a countable union of closed disks.

For the theorem, closed disks are used because it is (slightly) easier to see that

$$\mu_E(f) \in D$$

if $E = f^{-1}(D)$ has positive measure for closed disks than for open disks (non-strict inequalities are often slightly easier to prove than strict inequalities), but one can also use open disks for the proof. Or more generally any closed or open convex sets. Closed disks just yield an easier proof.

Comment: But second countability means there is a countable basis for the topology. That is every open can be written as *arbitrary* union of these, or?

Comment: A subset of a countable set is again countable. So from a countable basis, you can only obtain countable unions.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh right, thanks alot!!

Comment: By the way, where does the requirement of convexity become necessary in the proof of Lebesgue's mean value theorem? The only needed so far is closedness, isn't it?

Comment: If $S$ is not convex, then the mean value $\mu_E(f)$ for $E \subset f^{-1}(S)$ with positive measure usually does not lie in $S$. Take an annulus for example, $A = \{ z : 1 \leqslant \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2\}$. Then you would not be surprised that $\mu_E(f) = 0$ for some $E\subset f^{-1}(A)$, would you? The condition that ensures that all mean values over subsets of $f^{-1}(S)$ (for all measurable $f$) lie in $S$ is convexity (closedness or openness of $S$ is not necessary, I think, but if $S$ is neither open nor closed, the proof would get difficult).

Comment: Ah so it is not necessary for the proof but in order for assumption to hold it will be usually convex...

Comment: There are two directions. One, "if all averages lie in $S$, then $f^{-1}(S^c)$ is a null set". That doesn't need convexity of $S$. The other, "if $f^{-1}(S^c)$ is a null set, then all averages lie in $S$" needs the convexity of $S$.